# How can you specify a unique user in Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-analytics-firebase, userid

I am trying to match each user with the respective advertising_id, vendor_id, user_id and user_pseudo_id.

Since forever I was using the user_pseudo_id as the trusted unique identifier since it is always present in the data that returned (other ids sometimes return as NULL).

But lately I have noticed that user_pseudo_id can be the same for multiple users (symptom is there are events of multiple devices with the same user_pseudo_id; with differrent vendor_id and advertising_id though)

I cannot use CONCAT of those 3 ids as a unique key since most of the time 1 of them would be NULL or BLANK

Do you guys have any ideas to handle this problem or should I just ignore it since it doesn't really accounts for that much compares to the total number of users?

[image: Different device with different id but same user_pseudo_id]

Comment: To create a unique key by concatenating multiple columns with Null values, you can use the [IfNULL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#ifnull) function to check if the value is NULL, and to replace it with an empty/any_value for concatenation. Example: `SELECT CONCAT(IFNULL(CAST(user_pseudo_id AS STRING),'1'),IFNULL(CAST(user_id AS STRING),'1'),IFNULL(CAST(vendor_id AS STRING),'1'),IFNULL(CAST(advertising_id AS STRING),'1')) FROM table;`. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: What about your Google Analytics 4 settings? Have you verified your reporting identity? https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10976610 Also I recommend to check your Google Signals settings. There is a nice post on linkedin where you can see the difference in counts in GA4 interface if you disable / enable Google Signals. I wouldn't be surprise if there is something going on in BigQuery as well. https://www.linkedin.com/posts/charlesfarina_there-are-many-articles-suggesting-you-should-activity-6968300792638296064-6DWw